# How to configure email service of Review board with Microsoft exchange server

Tags: review-board, microsoft-exchange

I am trying to configure the email service for my Review board. I think I should configure it in the web page of `{Your_review_board_address}/admin/settings/email/`. However, when I test it by mark the option "Send a test e-mail after saving", it always fail.

From my Outlook Web App page, I found the Mail Server should be smtp.office365.com, and the port number should be 587 for TLS authentication. However, what should I set for the username and password? Should it be my email address or my company account name? Any suggestion is welcome!

Thank you in advance!

System:
       Red Hat Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers at here are very helpful:
https://community.bitnami.com/t/how-to-configure-email-service-with-microsoft-exchange-server/54489

(Answer author's user name: jariza)